# Is there a way to return a number from fetch in typescript

Tags: php, typescript

Im trying to do some amateur project which includes making a calculator in html file with TypeScript, JavaScript and PHP functions. The conditions are set above me, so I have very little room for improvisation.
In one TypeScript file im trying to fetch a function from PHP file and then return a solution from it in the TypeScript class. Its a result of addition of 2 numbers. But i dont know how to feth and then return only result number from fetch() in class.

```
class Calculator
{
    private add(operands: Operands): number {
        let x = 0;
        fetch(`operation.php?f=add&x=2&y=2`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => x=data)
        console.log(x)
        return x;
    }
}
```

If i try to return x from fetch() i get error "Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'number'."

```
    private add(operands: Operands): number {
        let x = 0;
        x = fetch(`operation.php?f=add&x=2&y=2`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => x=data)
        console.log(x)
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: You can't. fetch is asynchronous, so the function that's using fetch must also be asyncronous.

Comment: So, there i a way for me to call function from PHP file in TypeScript other than Fetch?

Comment: No, all network calls are asynchronous. You should not try to return a number from a function, you need to return a `Promise<number>` and deal with it. there's no good reasonable way around this.